# Focusing SearchView so the soft keyboard appears?

Tags: android

I have a project that targets api 11 and above, so no actionbarsherlock.

I'm starting an activity with a SearchView. I want to focus the SearchView immediately, and have the soft keyboard up (if there's no hardware keyboard). I've tried:

```
mSearchView.requestFocus();
mSearchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

which does in fact focus the searchview, but it doesn't show the keyboard. I've read through other posts saying it's worked. Other posts try to force the keyboard up using:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(
    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

which will show the keyboard, but then it behaves strangely after I submit a search query - it hides itself, then pops up again, then hides itself finally.

Anyone have a correct way of getting this to work?

Thanks

-------- Edit ----------------

Here's how I'm setting it up:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    ...     

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    if (!mDidThisOnce) {
        mSearchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
        InputMethodManager imm = ...;
        imm.toggleSoftInput(...);
        mDidThisOnce = true;
    }
}
```

------ Last Edit -----------

So this works, but I needed to keep a flag to make sure I didn't run the imm code more than once, otherwise it keeps popping the keyboard up after you submit a search.

Comment: have you tried with [`mSearchView.setIconofied(false);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconified(boolean))?

Comment: I want to leave the SearchView expanded always, so I'm leaving that set to true.

Comment: where did you put the `imm.toggleSoftInput`?

Comment: I put it at the end of onCreateOptionsMenu() after my searchview becomes available. I also tried putting it in a runnable with postDelayed(). Updated my Q to include that code.

Comment: It's an old question, sill: to get rid of the flag, try posting a runnable on your main view, that executes the show keyboard code, so this will only happen once and it will wait for the view to get rendered, so the menu is surely created already

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I have used `searchView.clearFocus();` before and that worked for me.